# Add Taxonomy Subcategory To Permalink

Tags: custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, taxonomy, urls

I am using a custom post type (job_listing) and custom taxnomy (job_listing_category) via the Job Manager plugin.

I came across a guide in the plugin's documentation, to "add the Job’s category name to the base url. E.g. /job/**job-category**/job-title" ([here](https://wpjobmanager.com/document/tutorial-changing-the-job-slugpermalink/), the one before last).

It works great.

Instead of

- */job/my-nightclub-job/*

the permalinks change to

- */job/clubs/my-nightclub-job/*

The thing is, I want the permalinks to include also the sub-category which the post is a part of, meaning:

- /job/clubs/nightclubs/my-nightclub-job/

I first tried, on the post editing page, to mark V only on the sub-category and not on the main category (instead of marking V on both of them), to make it happen. But it just does

- */job/nightclubs/my-nightclub-job/*

Then I tried to add the following lines to the built-in function from earlier:

```
                $taxonomy_name = 'job_listing_category';
                $termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $first_term->term_id );

                foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
                    $child_term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
                    $child_term_slug = $term->slug;
                    
                    $job_listing_category .= $child_term_slug . '/';
                }
```

(on line 20)

But it does not work either.

What can I do to show the subcategory in the permalink of a custom taxonomy? :(